# What is mathematical basis for the percent symbol (%)?

Tags: notation, arithmetic

Percent means 1 part of 100 or 1/100 and is indicated with %.  Per mille means 1 part of 1000 or 1/1000 and is indicated with ‰, so it seems that these symbols indicate the mathematical operations that they perform (i.e., the divisor in per mille is 10X greater.  However I can't seem to reconcile how % suggests 1/100 and ‰ suggests 1/1000.

Is this just convention or is there a deeper meaning?

Thank you.

Comment: Have you seen [this](http://www.roma.unisa.edu.au/07305/symbols.htm#Percent)?

Comment: % has two 0s and a slanted 1 in it, and likewise for ‰... :)

Comment: @Rahul: you made up the "slanted 1", right?  That's why you put the :) joke sign at the end?

Comment: @GEdgar, as far as I know, I made up everything in that comment.

Comment: @Rahul: It's a good mnemonic nonetheless...

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It's a convention that started sort of as a fluke. In a 14th century Italian manuscript, a sideways letter P is written to stand for 'per 100' or 'per cento'. It then slowly evolved. A more in depth bit can be found under the percent sign history [here](http://web.archive.org/web/20120304192730/http://www.roma.unisa.edu.au/07305/symbols.htm#Percent), and on the [wiki page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent_sign#Evolution).

In addition to percent 0/0, and permil 0/00, there is also permyriad 0/000 for 1/10000.

Comment: I can't find it; is there a permyriad symbol in Unicode or $\TeX$? :)

Comment: Unicode U+2031 ‱, as referenced [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basis_point#cite_note-2)