# Where does the % symbol originate from?

Tags: notation, math-history

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is mathematical basis for the percent symbol (%)?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/62044/what-is-mathematical-basis-for-the-percent-symbol)

Where does the **%** symbol originate from?

Comment: See [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/62044/what-is-mathematical-basis-for-the-percent-symbol)

Answer (score 1):

[This is has a decent explanation.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent_sign)

Comment: with a decent warning *...This section's factual accuracy is disputed...*