# Why does 100% represent the whole of something

Tags: ratio

I want to start off by saying I'm not someone who is particularly strong at math, and that this is a fairly abstract question.

Today I was reading a comment on reddit, a user posted something to the effect of if you aren't sure 100000% about doing something, you shouldn't do it. I was annoyed by the percentage they used, it's obvious that you can't have more than 100% of something. (without going over the maximum quantity)

This got me thinking. Why does 100% represent the maximum value of something?

Let's say I took a test with 10 questions and got all 10 correct. I would have received a 100% on the test. Why? Why doesn't 200% or any other number represent the maximum percent that I can achieve?

I think it might be an arbitrary value chosen. It's easy to convert numbers to percentages with 100% being the maximum.

In summary, why does 1/1 = 100%? Why doesn't 1/1 = 200%, or 137.45%?

Comment: I agree with you in that it's an arbitrary choice. However, in everyday speech, the percentages are a constant object of exaggeration, so it's normal to say "Give your 110%" even though it's actually impossible.

Comment: There are of course cases where percentages greater than 100 make sense: if the economy can grow 2% in one year, then it can grow 200% in 50 years. But such percentages are dangerous; many people will fail to recognise that growing by 200% means tripling in size. Phrases like "give 110% of your best" are at best a lame joke and at worst innumerate pseudo-science.

Comment: See also: [What is mathematical basis for the percent symbol (%)?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/62044/what-is-mathematical-basis-for-the-percent-symbol)

Comment: "Give your 110%" can make sense if 100% means something like "giving your maximum output without stressing yourself". Then 110% just means going a little above that.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[Percent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percentage) literally means "per hundred", as "cent" means "hundred" in French (and, originally, Latin).  Hence, "percent" means "out of 100".

100% means 100 out of 100.

Comment: It comes from Latin _per centum_.

Answer (score 2):

100% means $\frac{100}{100}$ (Hundred out of Hundred). In short If an apple is divided to 100 parts and you ate 5 parts, you have eaten 5% of it. you cannot eat more than 100%.

Answer (score 2):

As already said, 100% means 100 out of 100.

To me, the only two ways to read a percentage superior to 100 is :

- An oral way of emphasizing something ("I'm 1000% sure of what I'm saying"), which is mathematically wrong.
- Talking about a rate. If a plant measures 10cm on Monday, then 20cm on Friday, it has a 100% growth rate. But if it measures, again, 10cm on Monday and then 30cm on Friday, it has a 200% growth rate. You often see this when talking/reading about economic growth.